# SQL query giving records even not exists

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT project.id, project.title project_title, project.approval_status, office.office office_name, project.date_submitted, project.reason_for_rejection
FROM project
JOIN user ON project.user_id = user.id
JOIN office ON user.office_id = office.id
WHERE EXISTS
(
        SELECT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, t3.id id3, t4.id id4, t5.id id5
        FROM user t1
        LEFT JOIN user t2 ON t2.reports_to = t1.id
        LEFT JOIN user t3 ON t3.reports_to = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN user t4 ON t4.reports_to = t3.id
        LEFT JOIN user t5 ON t5.reports_to = t4.id
        WHERE t1.id = (
            SELECT id
            FROM user
            WHERE office_id = 52
            AND reports_to = 22
        )
)
```

This is are the records returned by the query

[image]

However I only want the records that exist in this query

```
SELECT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, t3.id id3, t4.id id4, t5.id id5
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN user t2 ON t2.reports_to = t1.id
LEFT JOIN user t3 ON t3.reports_to = t2.id
LEFT JOIN user t4 ON t4.reports_to = t3.id
LEFT JOIN user t5 ON t5.reports_to = t4.id
WHERE t1.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM user
    WHERE office_id = 52
    AND reports_to = 22
)
```

which gives this records when I run it

[image]

I only want the records which have `project.user_id` that exists in this query.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: There is no connection between the select and the subselect. You should use `IN` instead of `EXISTS`.

Comment: @JimmyT Thank you. I've tried using `IN` and it works.

Comment: Could't the `where` clause be simplified to `t1.office_id = 52 and t1.reports_to = 22`?  Why a sub-query?